# MYSQL Join on JSON column which contains array data

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables on each other.
This is the layout (simplified):

TABLE: items

| id (INT) | gift_cards (TEXT) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id":"6392"},{"id":"6393"}] |

TABLE: order

| id (INT) | code_id (INT) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6392 |

How can i join the two tables based on items.item (and than the id value) and order.value?

Here is what i have tried, but that doesn't work:

```
select aga.code_id, ago.gift_cards from order aga
inner join items ago ON JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(ago.gift_cards, '$[*]'
    COLUMNS (
        id text PATH '$.id'
)), CAST(ago.gift_cards AS JSON), '$') = aga.code_id
```

That gives this error:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( id text PATH '$.id' )), CAST(ago.gift_cards AS JSON), '$') = aga.code_' at line 3
```

Comment: It seems that you must apply JSON_TABLE instead of JSON_EXTRACT..